# Vsync event callback or listener in Android sdk

Tags: android, vsync

Is there Vsync event callback or listener in Android SDK?

I Need to do some sync in app to make sure there only 1 operation in every 1 Vsync

Answer (score 0):

Is `Choreographer.postFrameCallback(FrameCallback callback)` ok for your needs?